# Filter SQL query after joins while excluding rows from joined tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query with 3 joins that I am using to get to try to get the count of rows in the initially selected table using an id in the last table. The query looks as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM event
INNER JOIN user ON event.user_id = user.id
INNER JOIN membership ON membership.user_id = user.id
INNER JOIN team ON team.id = membership.team_id
WHERE event_type = 'S' 
AND team.id = 1;
```

So the goal is to get the count of events using the `team.id` and only include the count for that specific `team.id`. The problem I'm facing is that a `user` can be on multiple teams over time and currently this query is returning the count for event rows of all teams the user was related to through the membership relation. For example, if the user is first on a team with `team.id` = 1 and later on another team with `team.id` = 2 and there were 5 event rows that were created for each team, the above query currently returns the result as `10` instead of `5`.

Maybe I'm thinking about this incorrectly, but is there a way to filter the query so only the count of the rows associated with `team.id` = 1 is returned?

Thanks!

Comment: there' should be relationship between your team and event tables. users might have different teams.

Comment: It seems the `team.id = 1` condition should solve this problem. Can you demonstrate it with some sample data?

Comment: @spheres . .  I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: I updated it to just postgreql. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to filter first and then join -

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM event
INNER JOIN user ON event.user_id = user.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, team_id
            FROM membership
            WHERE team_id = 1) M ON M.user_id = user.id
INNER JOIN team ON team.id = M.team_id
WHERE event_type = 'S'
AND team.id = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but unfortunately I get the same result with this as with the original query.

Comment: @spheres, May you please try now? If this also doesn't solves your problem, please provide the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to count distinct users.  That would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.id)
FROM event e JOIN
     user u
     ON e.user_id = u.id JOIN
     membership m
     ON m.user_id = u.id JOIN
     team t
     ON t.id = m.team_id
WHERE event_type = 'S' AND t.id = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. My goal is actually to count the total distinct events rather than the users though. I tried amending the above to:

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.id)
FROM event e JOIN
     user u
     ON e.user_id = u.id JOIN
     membership m
     ON m.user_id = u.id JOIN
     team t
     ON t.id = m.team_id
WHERE event_type = 'S' AND t.id = 1;`

But this gets the same result of a count that is the combined total from both teams (id=1 and id=2)